# Tkinter, How to do destroy the button I click in a grid made by a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
for x in range(xBtns):
    for y in range(yBtns):

        btn = Button(board, width=2, height=1)
        btn.grid(column=x, row=y)
        btn.bind('<Button-3>', btnFunction)
```

Where btnFunction deletes the button that was right-clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `event` object that is passed to a bound function contains a reference to the widget that received the event:

```
def btnFunction(event):
    event.widget.destroy()
```

Comment: I tried that and got "NameError: name 'destroy' is not defined"

Comment: @Mrchooch: my mistake. My description was correct but my example was wrong.  I fixed my answer.

Comment: Ok it works now, but despite that every time you delete a button it says "AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'destroy'"

Comment: @Mrchooch: read the error message closely, look at what I wrote, and then look at your code. You apparently are calling `event.destroy()`, which is not what this answer suggests to do.

Comment: My bad, ignore me, forgot to remove the old code XD

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
canvas.delete("all")
```

when the button is clicked.